# EAS build keeps an old version of the code and doesn’t update with the latest changes

Tags: expo, eas

I have built production app with EAS Build.

Build versions uses channel production which is linked to branch production.

After running "eas update" I can see the different updates under that tab. The deployment is also showing the correct branch and the name of the new change.

However, the AAB file contains code that I built ages ago. It also shows the old icon.
I have tried clearing the cache, but it is not solving the issue.

Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.